# Insert response to command from Jsch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I need to run a Unix command from java using Jsch. When I execute this command in the local console of my server, the console shows me a message to insert some parameters:

```
$ cd /mycinema
$ films
$ Insert the title:
```

But I do not know how to capture this from java so I can detect that it requires a parameter and be able to insert the title and return the result of the movie without closing the channel or session. Any ideas? My code right now is this (copied from another thread in this forum):

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SSHConnectionManager {

    private Session session;

    private String username = "user";
    private String password = "pass";
    private String hostname = "server";

    public SSHConnectionManager() { }

    public SSHConnectionManager(String hostname, String  , String password) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void open() throws JSchException {
        open(this.hostname, this.username, this.password);
    }

    public void open(String hostname, String username, String password) throws JSchException{

        JSch jSch = new JSch();

        session = jSch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        Properties config = new Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  // not recommended
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(password);

        System.out.println("Connecting SSH to " + hostname + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    }

    public String runCommand(String command) throws JSchException, IOException {

        String ret = "";

        if (!session.isConnected())
            throw new RuntimeException("Not connected to an open session.  Call open() first!");

        ChannelExec channel = null;
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream(); // channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        ret = getChannelOutput(channel, in);

        channel.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Finished sending commands!");

        return ret;
    }


    private String getChannelOutput(Channel channel, InputStream in) throws IOException{

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = "";
        while (true){
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                strBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, i));
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            if(line.contains("logout")){
                break;
            }

            if (channel.isClosed()){
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee){}
        }

        return strBuilder.toString();   
    }

    public void close(){        
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected channel and session");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        SSHConnectionManager ssh = new SSHConnectionManager();
        try {
            ssh.open();
            String ret = ssh.runCommand("cd /mycinema; films;");              

            System.out.println(ret);
            ssh.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a way too broad. Do you really want to implement a heuristic system that checks prompts and tries to answer them? Or do you know what inputs will the command ask for? In which case you can just blindly feed predetermined input to the command.

Comment: Really, I do know that I can know what is going to respond. Could I pass this parameter at the time of executing the command?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the duplicate.